# How to recode variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I tried to recode the missing values but instead lost all my other variables within a dataset

---

BEFORE:

[image]

---

AFTER:

```
        data work.newdataset;
        if (year =.) then year = 2000;
        run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the SET statement.

```
data want;
set have;
myvar=5;
run;
```

will create a new dataset, `want`, from `have`, with the new variable value applied (or the recode or whatever).  You could also do

```
data have;
set have;
myvar=5;
run;
```

That would replace `have` with itself plus the recode/whatever.  This is actually less common in SAS; it is often preferable to do all recodes in one step, but to create a new dataset (so that the code is reversible easily).